# Mainframe access to Facebook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-authentication

I am working on a request to allow our Unisys mainframe users to access their Facebook data from non-GUI terminals. Based on the "no scraping, no automation" Facebook terms-of-service, and the way Facebook's oAuth authentication works, I don't see how the mainframe software can log on to the user's account to access/update their data.

Does Facebook support any kind of authentication that does not require a person sitting at a GUI screen?

Comment: Wow. Probably the first facebook & mainframe question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Rod,

The thing that stopped me was the OAUTH code. Twitter (and I believe Facebook) allow an API connection via OAuth. You have to create the callback and use the Unisys CryptoAPI to handle some digest creation. Another way I did it was to use the MCP JProcessor and implement it on that front, but I am sure you are looking for an ALGOL way to do it. If you have a need to add the OAUTH code and can handle the special SHA2-256 it would work from ALGOL.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. No. They don't offer this.